# Fire bootstrap modal from a highcharts x axis label?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a line chart in highcharts with the xaxis labels as links.  When I click them I want to open up a small bootstrap modal.  Right now I have them clickable as links, but they just fire to a new page and don't open the modal.  When I view page source it looks like it built the links correctly.  Anyone know how to do this?

My X-axis from my Highcharts function:

```
xAxis: {
          title: {
            text: 'Stock Price'
          },
          labels:{
            rotation: -45,
            formatter: function(){
              return '<a data-toggle="modal" href="details?price=' + this.value + '" data-target="#myModal">' + '$ ' + this.value + '</a>';
            },
            useHTML: true
          },
          categories: [#{strikeprices}]
        },
```

Can you not build a modal link in this way in the javascript of the page and still have it fire?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Accord to [this comment](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2225#issuecomment-24219630) and [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/DwJaS/), the appropriate way to handle it is to figure out what elements/classes are being used on the access titles, and add listeners to them using jQuery to fire the modal. So something like

```
$('elements that wrap the title').on('click', function() {
  $('#modalID').modal('show');
});
```

You should be able to get the elements in Chrome by right clicking on the title and doing an "inspect element."

Comment: so when inspecting on the individual links there is no elements at all just the links I created:  <a data-toggle="modal" href="details?price=17.5" data-target="#myModal">$ 17.5</a>  However on a div that covers all these links there is this:  <div class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-xaxis-labels">.  Would I use one of these classes for the onclick?

Comment: I actually did it with the way your link said was no longer working.  Not sure if I have an earlier version of highcharts or if this is actually a security threat but this works for firing a modal:  formatter: function(){
                  return '<a href="javascript:$(\'#myModal\').modal(\'show\')">' + '$ ' + this.value + '</a>';
                },    But Now How to I send the x axis label value to that modal? or use this to call an href of a remote modal passing the value in the query string?

Comment: Sorry this wasn't clear in the answer, but you should probably remove your custom formatter completely, then hook in to the default elements/classes that highcharts builds for you.

Comment: Thanks Sean I was able to get it working with the solution below, but as mentioned in the link you provided is this not a best practice?  I am not entirely clear how to make it clickable without the customer formatter.

Answer (score 0):

Well I was able to get it to work.  But not sure if its the best method.  I did using javascript in the a href tag as such:

```
xAxis: {
          title: {
            text: 'Stock Price'
          },
          labels:{
            rotation: -45,
            formatter: function(){
              return '<a href="javascript:$(\'#myModal\').modal({remote: \'/details?price=' + this.value + '\'});$(\'#myModal\').modal(\'show\');">' + '$ ' + this.value + '</a>';
            },
            useHTML: true
          },
          categories: [#{strikeprices}]
        },
```

Notice there are two functions called.  The first sets a remote url for the modal passing the x axis label value.  Then the second fires the modal.  It works, but is it a bad practice to launch JavaScript in a link like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [custom-events](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events) extension which allows to catch click event on the axis labels.